# Why is the navigation/menu bar taking a long time to load?

Tags: performance, web, content-management-system, loading, navigationbar

I'm trying to address the slow loading speed of [this website](https://www.protectpt.org/). We delved into the network traffic and found that much of the APIs (Google Maps, Facebook, etc.) are causing the slow load.

What we are having a hard time figuring out is the staggered loading of the navigation bar on the homepage. The navigation bar is not an image but a series of styled texts. Would you be so kind to share your thoughts on why the navigation bar takes a longer time to load? More importantly, what we can do to speed this up so it loads like other components on the webpage?

We are using a CMS and are willing to make some changes. Any other suggestions for speed improvement are welcome!